# Can we merge [whatsapp] with [whatsapi]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) tag (used on 71 questions) with the following wiki description.

> Use [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) if your question is relating to whatsapp API. Web or Mobile based application

There is also a [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) tag (used on 1207 questions).

> WhatsApp Messenger is a proprietary, cross-platform instant messaging application for smartphones. In addition to basic messaging and video calling, WhatsApp Messenger users can send each other images, video and audio media messages.

---

Since the [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) tag exists, we don't need the [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) tag. It will be on topic on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) and will be off topic here.

As a side note, I am not sure if [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) is the official term to refer to it.

So, should we combine both and rename them to [whatsapp-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-api)?

Comment: WhatsAPI may refer to [this PHP project](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation).

Comment: @Justastudent then the info is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/tags/whatsapi/info

Comment: WhatsApp appears to not really expose an API, as everything is centered around devices and can hence not be controlled via a service. There is [some kind of API](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013) for use on devices, though.

Comment: I am only speculating, @Sagar. The tag and wiki are both rather vague, honestly.

Comment: how about the proposal [tag:whatsapp-api] ?

Comment: @Justastudent that's not a "WhatsApp API", that's just documenting which iOS APIs the WhatsApp app has registered with.

Comment: Come on, it's just a different letter! :P

Comment: and a new tag for one letter :P

Comment: If the tags should be merged, I would first go through all [tag:whatsapp] questions and eliminate the off-topic ones.

Comment: Exactly. You may found questions suits for ask different or android she

Comment: I'd say get rid of the [tag:whatsapi] tag since it seems un-used, the tag info is poorly written, and WhatsApp doesn't provide an API.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose:

- Clean-up [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) and improve the tag wiki. There are questions that are [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600971/get-whatsapp-password-from-whatsapp-api) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426079/whatsapp-chatapi-statusfail-reasonincorrect-issue) [WhatsAPI: part of Chat-API, a PHP WhatsApp library](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation). However, there are many that are misusing it as general [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) due to the confusing tag excerpt.
- Leave [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) tag. Most of the tagged questions are about interacting with WhatsApp through programming.
- No need for [whatsapp-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-api) since WhatsApp doesn't provide *an official API* (except [this and the only one](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030)). WhatsApp provides a way to interact with its app ([Android](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/28000012), [iOS](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013)), but I don't think that's considered as an API.

Comment: Cleaned-up [tag:whatsapi] as of June 25. Now I see a problem. Apparently, there are 3 [whatsapi] library; PHP, .NET C#, and NodeJS.