# Can we remove or merge tag [whatsapi] with tag [whatsapp]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Tag [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi), all time 161 questions,

##### [Revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38596849/revisions):

1. Created on Jul 26, 2016:

   > Whatsapp allows direct linking to it's resources in mobile application. Whereby, you can create an application (eg Contact book) and directly have link to create message (or call) to a whatsapp user.
2. Edited on Jun 26, 2017:

   - **Removed disambiguation based on** [Can we merge [whatsapp] with [whatsapi]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350824)

   > WhatsAPI is part of Chat API, a PHP library for interfacing to WhatsApp Messenger. DO NOT USE this tag for general programming related to WhatsApp, use [whatsapp] instead.
   >
   > WhatsAPI is part of Chat API, a PHP library for interfacing to WhatsApp Messenger.

##### Purpose of removal or merge with [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)

The PHP Chat API library has been removed/deprecated for many days. I don't know the exact date, but I have been noticing that for six months users picking the [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) tag for different topics:

- [WhatsApp Business Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api) APIs (Cloud API, On-Premises API, and Business Management API)

  - Related to [facebook-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) and [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)
- [WhatsApp Web APIs](https://api.whatsapp.com/) (Integration with different languages and Mobile)

  - Related to [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)
- Third-party WhatsApp BSPs and their APIs ([twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio), [twilio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio-api), chat-api, etc.)

  - Related to [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) and their own tags if present

---

All questions are related to [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) tag, and we don't require [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) tag.

So should we remove the [whatsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapi) tag and merge all 161 present questions into the [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) tag?

Comment: What we should have are different tags for the different APIs (e.g. [whatsapp-cloud-api], [whatsapp-on-premises-api], [whatsapp-business-mgmt-api], [whatsapp-web-apis], [whatsapp-bsps]. We should remove [whatsapp] since the app is not used for programming itself (AFAIK).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, a good suggestion we can create those tags, but if we remove [whatsapp] tag then it's really lots of work, to assign specific WhatsApp API type tags to existing questions. Tag [whatsapp] all time 2818 questions!

Comment: Yeah, retagging questions is not fun. ‍♂️

Comment: What is [BSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bsp)? *Business <something> platform*? Or *[business solution provider](https://faq.whatsapp.com/695500918177858)*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, [Business Solution Providers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started-for-bsps) BSP integration documentation, and [List of BSPs](https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?solution_type=messaging&platforms=whatsapp) in Meta where people can connect with it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the WhatsAPI PHP library is dead due to legal threats by WhatsApp; the author wiped the GitHub repository completely. While that doesn't mean we should delete the existing questions that are actually about that library (anything pre-2016 with the tag probably is), I'm not sure it's particularly worth keeping them around, either... if someone still has the code, it could ostensibly still work (though it seems unlikely given the changes that Whatsapp has gone through since 2015).

Any question *not* about the WhatsAPI PHP library (probably any question tagged with it from 2016 onward) should definitely not have that tag applied.

Second, Whatsapp *itself* is a messaging app, so it's not on-topic here; we should not have the destination tag be named just [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp).

As far as I can tell, Whatsapp has no general 'end user' APIs, only APIs available for business uses (the "Whatsapp Developer Platform"). Despite your "Whatsapp Web APIs" link going to a live page with "API" in the URL, that appears to just offer a web-based version of the app, not an API... in fact for me it only offers a download option for what is presumably a desktop-based application.

On the Whatsapp Developer Platform, there are two or three (depending on how you look at it) different APIs:

- Whatsapp Business Management API - I think this one is just interacting with your own business account. You can generate business content (QR codes, campaigns) but can't use them or interact with customers. I think it is a REST API.

And then:

- Whatsapp Business On-Premises API - This is an on-premises (users need to host their own servers) solution that runs the API which businesses can use to interact with customers or do mass-marketing campaigns, etc. It's basically the same as Facebook's Marketing API. It uses Facebook's Graph API.
- Whatsapp Business Cloud API - new-ish (May 2022) hosted version of the On-Premises API. Less functional for now but the benefit is you don't have to manage or pay for your own servers.

This is a right mess, because as far as I can tell, there used to just be the "Whatsapp Business API"... and I have no idea whether it referred to the 1st or 2nd bulleted API above.

Given the above APIs, I would suggest the following tags:

- [whatsapp-business-mgmt-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-business-mgmt-api)
- [whatsapp-on-premises-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-on-premises-api)
- [whatsapp-cloud-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-cloud-api)

And cleaning up the questions to use one of those.

Comment: *"Second, Whatsapp itself is a messaging app, so it's not on-topic here; we should not have the destination tag be named just [whatsapp]."* Wait, that's exactly why it'd be fine to use the name [whatsapp] for the tag. It's why we can happily call it [python], without needing to call it [python-language] for fear of people asking for help on what to feed their pet constrictors. It's only confusing when the other thing is *also* on-topic. That said, I do still agree it is reasonable to break the tags up by API.

Comment: [tag:ms-word] and [tag:powerpoint] are both applications like WhatsApp.

Comment: @ZevSpitz It seems like your comment is just repeating what Cody's said.

Comment: @TylerH Just providing more specific parallel examples.

Comment: The last message was by [whatsapi](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) in May 2015. after that, It was cloned as [Chat-API](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API) and dead. answer explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31434801/8987128).

Comment: @turivishal If there's a spiritual successor to WhatsAPI, it should have a tag based on its own name. Looks like your link to Chat-API is also dead so I don't see much point in worrying about said successor at this point.